# Airflow: ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor' - wasb logger

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to configure remote logging with Azure blob.

```
Airflow version: 1.10.2
Python: 3.6.5
Ubuntu: 18.04
```

Following are the step I did:

1. In $AIRFLOW_HOME/config/log_config.py, I have put REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER = 'wasb-airflow-logs' (This is a folder inside the container (container name: airflow-logs))
2. Empty **init**.py is in $AIRFLOW_HOME/config/
3. $AIRFLOW_HOME/config/ is added in $PYTHONPATH
4. Renamed DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG to LOGGING CONFIG everywhere in $AIRFLOW_HOME/config/log_config.py
5. User defined in Airflow blob connection has read/write access to REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
6. $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg it has remote_logging = True
   logging_config_class = log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG
   remote_log_conn_id =

Following is the error:

```
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 382, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
AttributeError: module 'airflow.utils.log' has no attribute 'wasb_task_handler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 384, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/wasb_task_handler.py", line 23, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.hooks.wasb_hook import WasbHook
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/wasb_hook.py", line 22, in <module>
    from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 28, in <module>
    from airflow.models import Connection
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 86, in <module>
    from airflow.utils.dag_processing import list_py_file_paths
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py", line 49, in <module>
    from airflow.settings import logging_class_path
ImportError: cannot import name 'logging_class_path'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 708, in configure_handler
    klass = self.resolve(cname)
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 391, in resolve
    raise v
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 384, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/wasb_task_handler.py", line 23, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.hooks.wasb_hook import WasbHook
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/wasb_hook.py", line 22, in <module>
    from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 28, in <module>
    from airflow.models import Connection
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 86, in <module>
    from airflow.utils.dag_processing import list_py_file_paths
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py", line 49, in <module>
    from airflow.settings import logging_class_path
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'airflow.utils.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler': cannot import name 'logging_class_path'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/bin/airflow", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from airflow import settings, configuration as conf
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 262, in <module>
    logging_class_path = configure_logging()
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 73, in configure_logging
    raise e
  File "/home/gsingh/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 68, in configure_logging
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/home/gsingh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': Cannot resolve 'airflow.utils.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler': cannot import name 'logging_class_path'
```

I am not sure which configuration I am missing. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the azure package.

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[azure_blob_storage,azure_data_lake,azure_cosmos,azure_container_instances]
```

As per [updating.md](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e62ad5333c/UPDATING.md)

This now should be installed with

```
pip install apache-airflow[azure]
```

But this didn't work for me.

Comment: `pip install apache-airflow[azure]` has been deprecated in airflow 1.10.3;

Comment: Good to know, poorly documented.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error however if I scrolled up higher I could see that there was another exception thrown before the ValueError. Which was a PermissionError.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler'
```

The reason I got that error is because I didn't create the initial 3 folders (dags, logs, plugins) before running airflow docker container. So docker seems to have created then automatically but the permissions were wrong.

Steps to fix:

1. Stop current container

```
docker-compose down --volumes --remove-orphans
```

2. Delete folders dags, logs, plugins
3. Just in case Destroy the images and volumes already created (in Docker Desktop)
4. Create folders again from command line

```
mkdir logs dags plugins
```

5. run airflow docker again

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
docker-compose up
```

Comment: @Gagan perhaps you want to reconsider marking my answer as the solution as it seems to help more people?

Answer (score 5):

`sudo chown 50000:0 dags logs plugins` in my case.

I tried to run official `docker-compose.yml` with all these containers (which are dependent on these 3 volume forwards) or simply wrap `airflow standalone` into a single container for a debug purpose. Turned out volumes were created with root ownerships instead of airflows.